# Read go.mod and detect the version of project

Tags: regex, go

Mostly, `go.mod` file looks something like this :

```
module <module_name>

go 1.16

require (...)
```

Now, I want to extract the version value `1.16` in another golang project
I read the file and stored it in a buffer.

```
buf, err := ioutil.ReadFile(goMODfile)
if err != nil {
    return false, err.Error()
}
```

I guess `FindString()` or `MatchString()` functions can help me out here, but I am not sure how !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of regexp you could just use [`"golang.org/x/mod/modfile"`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/mod@v0.5.1/modfile) to parse the `go.mod` file's contents.

```golang
f, err := modfile.Parse("go.mod", file_bytes, nil)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(f.Go.Version)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/XETDzMcTwS_S

---

If you have to use regexp, then you could do the following:

```golang
re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)^go (\d+\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$`)
match := re.FindSubmatch(file_bytes)
version := string(match[1])
```

https://play.golang.org/p/L5-LM67cvgP

Answer (score 2):

The simple way to report information about a Go module is to use [`go list`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-List_packages_or_modules). You can use the `-m` flag to list properties of modules and the `-f` flag to report specific fields. If no specific module is given, `go list -m` reports information about the main module (containing the current working directory).

For example, to list the `GoVersion` for the main module:

```
$ go list -f {{.GoVersion}} -m
```